# AngularJs SEO Title Support

Tags: angularjs

We have a catalog that loads an AngularJS application dynamically according to the defined subdomain. For example: http://subdomain.billiving.biz

We need to support dynamic title that will be set by AngularJS. I saw in Google documentation that we need to add this link:

```
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

Anything else we should do to set this correctly?
Thanks

Comment: Google have deprecated the hash fragment URL scheme, HTML5 mode is the way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually ended up using Push-State. This includes two changes:

1. Enabling Html5Mode:

   ```
   .config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
       $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true});
   }]);
   ```
2. Providing a base href from your app (when working local need full localhost path)

   `<base href="/">`

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow HashBang URL standard or HTML5  URL

Something like

```
angular.module('app', []).config(['$locationProvider', function($location) {
  $location.hashPrefix('!');
}]);
```

Here is the good guide to follow [Angular SEO](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html)